# SQL: De-duplicating based on nested IF statement:

Tags: sql

My base table (name: `duplicates`) has the list of duplicated `product_id`. None of the distinct `product_id` are included. I need to de-duplicate based on the following criteria:

```
product_id  in_stock    price   sales_channel
A112233     NULL        12.95   Online
A112233     11345678    12.95   Store
A112233     12466654    11.95   NULL
```

1. First, take the `product_id` which is `in_stock` in our database (indicated by `NOT NULL`)
2. If duplicates still persist, then take the `product_id` with lowest `price`
3. If duplicates still persist, then take the `product_id` where  `sales_channel = ‘Online’`
4. If duplicates still persist, then take one random row for each `product_id`
5. **Consider that `in_stock` and `sales_channel` can contain `NULL` values

I was trying to leverage the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to provide rankings to each partition, but I’m not sure how to code this since it’s not based on a static partition (partition will change as certain `product_id` are disregarded).

Anyone done this before?

Comment: i removed all the extraneous tags. please tag the question with the *one* dbms you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, all you need is to add more conditions to the `ORDER BY` clause, like this:

```
with a as(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id 
ORDER BY CASE in_stock IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
         price,
         CASE COALESCE(sales_channel, '') = 'Online' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as rn
from duplicates)
select * from a where rn = 1
```